# Adaptive UI solution for Meteor on both desktop and mobile

Tags: user-interface, mobile, meteor, meteoric

I am trying to build an app that can fit in both desktop screen and mobile platform like iOS and Android.

I have tried with Meteoric [Build Meteor apps with Ionic](http://meteoric.github.io/) but it only adjust the problem with mobile UI. If I also want the app to display decently on desktop screen, what techniques or framework I should adopt?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use bootstrap or similar framework to achieve this with its small, medium and large size constraints etc. available and then adapt the CSS to work with your app.

Alternatively or as well as above, you could also create different Routes for mobile devices compared to web devices using the `Meteor.isCordova` blocks as well as something like the `jscd.js` javascript tool to detect mobile devices and redirecting accordingly. (this is what I do with some of my web/mobile apps)

And the other way i would suggest is a secondary app for mobile devices using a common core package (thats if you want to go down the route of multiple apps and packaging your components)

Comment: Hi @Aaron. Thanks for the suggestion. I am trying to customize bootstrap as suggested in your first approach. I think there is a need for this kind of framework (or github project) since more projects will be on both mobile app (wrapped by phonegap) and desktop, and it save lots of time.